# XMLHttpRequest giving super weird inconsistent results in react native with expo image picker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image, expo, xmlhttprequest

EDIT: i've got a theory that my weird result on web is due to some unusual polyfill but i have no idea how to fix it, why its only happening to me or whats with the weird JSON stuff on mobile so please help.

So my upload function is based off of the code example with firebase in expo image picker here:

https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-firebase-storage-upload

They're using XMLHttpRequest instead of fetch and advise to do the same but its giving me some really weird results.

For one, i know that the expo image picker returns a base64 string containing the actual data of the image rather than a uri on web. But it seemed like it was working on web before. I'm confirming the input with a console.log() and can confirm the base64 data IS indeed going through on web, BUT, on web what seems to be getting uploaded is an HTML snippet containing formatted text that says:

"Oh no! It looks like JavaScript is not enabled in your browser.

**Reload "**

Which... is just not true. Javascript is enabled in my browser otherwise the whole rest of the app wouldn't work but for some reason XMLHttpRequest in particular is just crapping out. And i can confirm that this is indeed what is coming out in my blob using another console.log().

---

```
const uploadPhoto = async (Photo) => {
        if (Photo) {
            //if it is a URI make a blob
            console.log(Photo);  
            const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                };
                xhr.onerror = function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
                };
                xhr.responseType = "blob";
                xhr.open("GET", Photo, true);
                xhr.send(null);
            });
            console.log(await blob.text());

            //create file ref
            const fileRef = ref(getStorage(), uuidv4());

            uploadBytes(fileRef, blob)
                .catch(error => {
                    alert(error);
                    return null;
                })
                .then(result => {
                    return result;
                })

        }
```

Furthermore, when i try to run on iOS, i'm getting this weird error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weuYl.jpg)
Which is showing up on my emulator, not my console and i don't know what to make of it because i've never seen a JSON value thrown as an error and can't find any record of this kind of thing happening to anyone else. Presumably this is the correct base64 image data but why is it coming up as some kind of error?

And then on android i can't even reach the submit button due to a different issue where scrollview doesn't scroll in the stack navigator on android but thats a separate problem i'm trying to solve unrelated to this issue. It just means i can't test this bug out on android yet.

Does anyone know wtf is going on? And also, since i can't find anyone out there that even seems to acknowledge the difference in output data between the web and mobile platforms of expo image picker, and the only reason i even know about it was because i pointed it out on reddit and some guy acted like i was the idiot for assuming the uri value WOULDN'T be base64 data on web and this was a feature not a bug... but since the output data is different on the web platform why do none of the guides that use expo image picker and firebase seem to acknowledge this difference and does it actually matter?